# Rule-of-thumb for Morse potential cutoff in molecular dynamics?

Tags: potential, computational-physics, simulations, molecular-dynamics

Is there a rule-of-thumb for selecting a cutoff for the Morse potential in molecular dynamics simulation? For instance, is it typically some multiple of the equilibrium distance?

Comment: This question might get more attention on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/#)

Comment: anneb: Much more about this has been explained in a recent answer on Materials Modeling Stack Exchange: https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/9/in-molecular-mechanics-how-are-van-der-waals-forces-modelled/557#557. The general guideline for when a potential goes from Morse-like to Lennard-Jones like is called the [Le Roy radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeRoy_radius) and I can explain more if you ask there.